# C# CheckedListBox.ItemCheck Event

Tags: c#

I am trying to "do something" when I check or uncheck a box in a checkedboxlist. I tried using the example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx but the event is never triggered when I check or uncheck a box.

I searched through answers and tried examples but none of them would give me any result when I checked a box.

```
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {    
        MessageBox.Show("ItemCheck Event");
    }
```

I know I am missing something simple but I've been running around in circles trying to find the solution. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Double-click ItemCheck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this handler to your `CheckBoxList.ItemCheck` event(in form constructor after `InitializeComponents()` or in `Load` handler):

```
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you